# Porting Kafka's murmur2 implementation to Go

Tags: java, go, hash, encoding, apache-kafka

JVM clients for Kafka are using custom implementation of murmur2 hash for their default partitioner.

None of Kafka clients for Go implement this hashing algorithm, which bring all sorts of problems when you need to keep consistent partitioning between different clients on different platforms.

I'm trying to port this code to Go, and it seems to work for some of the values, but not for the others.

Here is the Java code (source is here: https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/1.0.0/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/common/utils/Utils.java#L353
):

```
public static int murmur2(final byte[] data) {
    int length = data.length;
    int seed = 0x9747b28c;
    // 'm' and 'r' are mixing constants generated offline.
    // They're not really 'magic', they just happen to work well.
    final int m = 0x5bd1e995;
    final int r = 24;

    // Initialize the hash to a random value
    int h = seed ^ length;
    int length4 = length / 4;

    for (int i = 0; i < length4; i++) {
        final int i4 = i * 4;
        int k = (data[i4 + 0] & 0xff) + ((data[i4 + 1] & 0xff) << 8) + ((data[i4 + 2] & 0xff) << 16) + ((data[i4 + 3] & 0xff) << 24);
        k *= m;
        k ^= k >>> r;
        k *= m;
        h *= m;
        h ^= k;
    }

    // Handle the last few bytes of the input array
    switch (length % 4) {
        case 3:
            h ^= (data[(length & ~3) + 2] & 0xff) << 16;
        case 2:
            h ^= (data[(length & ~3) + 1] & 0xff) << 8;
        case 1:
            h ^= data[length & ~3] & 0xff;
            h *= m;
    }

    h ^= h >>> 13;
    h *= m;
    h ^= h >>> 15;

    return h;
}
```

Here is the Go code (playground link: https://play.golang.org/p/K4VooLZ4Mp7):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    cases := []struct {
        Input    []byte
        Expected int32
    }{
        {[]byte("21"), -973932308},
        {[]byte("foobar"), -790332482}, // outputs: 1518714010
        {[]byte("a-little-bit-long-string"), -985981536}, // outputs 2068422364
        {[]byte("a-little-bit-longer-string"), -1486304829}, // outputs 1797390322
        {[]byte("lkjh234lh9fiuh90y23oiuhsafujhadof229phr9h19h89h8"), -58897971}, // outputs -1332218133
        {[]byte{'a', 'b', 'c'}, 479470107},
    }

    for _, c := range cases {
        if res := murmur2(c.Input); res != c.Expected {
            fmt.Printf("input: %q, expected: %d, got: %d\n", c.Input, c.Expected, res)
        }
    }
}

func murmur2(data []byte) int32 {
    length := int32(len(data))
    seed := uint32(0x9747b28c)
    m := int32(0x5bd1e995)
    r := uint32(24)

    h := int32(seed ^ uint32(length))
    length4 := length / 4

    for i := int32(0); i < length4; i++ {
        i4 := i * 4
        k := int32(data[i4+0]&0xff) + (int32(data[i4+1]&0xff) << 8) + (int32(data[i4+2]&0xff) << 16) + (int32(data[i4+3]&0xff) << 24)
        k ^= int32(uint32(k) >> r)
        k *= m
        h *= m
        h ^= k
    }

    switch length % 4 {
    case 3:
        h ^= int32(data[(length & ^3)+2]&0xff) << 16
        fallthrough
    case 2:
        h ^= int32(data[(length & ^3)+1]&0xff) << 8
        fallthrough
    case 1:
        h ^= int32(data[length & ^3] & 0xff)
        h *= m
    }

    h ^= int32(uint32(h) >> 13)
    h *= m
    h ^= int32(uint32(h) >> 15)

    return h
}
```

I generated expected values for Go tests from Java, using mentioned `Utils` class like so:

`System.out.println(Utils.murmur2("a-little-bit-long-string".getBytes("UTF-8")))`

None of the existing murmur2 implementations for Go I've seen are generating the same results as mentioned Java code.

The question is, how can I port mentioned code in Java to Go so that the result will be the same between both?

Comment: Go version misses one multiplication statement: `k *= m` inside the loop.

Comment: @IskanderSharipov My God! Thanks a lot! So helpful to have someone with a fresh eye!

Comment: There's also xxHash which is already ported to Go here https://github.com/cespare/xxhash. It's supposed to be faster than the Murmur family.

Comment: Thank you so much for porting this! Almost spent half the day trying to do this as well myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed by @IskanderSharipov:

> Go version misses one multiplication statement: k *= m inside the loop